# The main thing is to create a database trigger that the price in my room table where the type is double must be greater than 100

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PriceMust

BEFORE INSERT ON ROOM

REFERENCE NEW AS new

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

     SELECT price, type

     From Room

     Where type =: 'Double'

     IF price<=: 100

                    raise_application_error('Price Must Be Over 100');
     END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Why would you only validate this on the insert? Why not use an ordinary constraint which applies to all inserts and updates?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll give you a cleaned up version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PriceMust
  BEFORE INSERT ON ROOM
  REFERENCING NEW AS new
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.TYPE = 'Double' and :NEW.price <= 100 THEN
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'Price Must Be Over 100');
   END IF;
END PRICEMUST;
/
```

The trigger is on the ROOM table, so you can't select from ROOM inside the trigger without getting a MUTATING TABLE error. Instead, just use the value in `NEW.TYPE` to determine the room type.

Best of luck.

Comment: Isn't it `referencing`, which is then redundant as you're changing something to itself? Plus, the entire thing is kinda pointless as it can be implemented better with a check constraint (not that we know what the OP is doing)

Comment: @Ben: thanks for catching the `REFERENCING`. And yes, it could be done with a CHECK constraint but OP seems to want a trigger.

Comment: thank you very much! my instructor doesnt know how to explain errors & we're using iacademy3...